# combobox columns

Tags: combobox, formatting

How can I display data in combobox in columns? I am using VB.net 2010 with SQL SERVER 2008. Or in other way, is it possible do accomplish this by formatting the sql query like using the formatting functions?

Comment: while I was searching for this point I found an easy solution for it.Using the replicate function in sql query solves this issue: SELECT empId as empId, STR(empId)+'  -->' + REPLICATE(' ', 15-DATALENGTH(empId)) + name as Employee
FROM EMPLOYEE;

Comment: but still I have the issue to make columns when working with varchar. though the function replaces the correct number of spaces but the length of the first token varies with the length of the drawing of the letters.

Comment: I think i should use pixels for length and loction